# What's an alternative to os.loadavg() for Windows

Tags: node.js, windows

Since `os.loadavg()` returns [0, 0, 0], is there any way of getting the CPU's average load in Windows based systems for 1, 5, and 15 minute intervals without having to check every few seconds and save the result yourself?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-cpu ?

Comment: Might want to add that an answer, that's exactly what I was looking for but for some reason wouldn't come up on npmjs even when I searched for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digging out this topic.

Use [loadavg-windows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadavg-windows) from npm to enable `os.loadavg()` on Windows.

**Wait few seconds to see first result different than 0.**

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `windows-cpu` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-cpu) to get similar results.

Comment: this package requires wmic and specific path, loadavg-windows seems to work without configuring path

Comment: Well, this answer is 6 years old. `loadavg-windows` wasn't a thing then. You're welcome.